# Routing like Sub Directory in Beego

Tags: go, beego

As of now i am routing like the following:

```
beego.Router("/detailed", &controllers.MainController{}, "get:Detailed")
```

Instead i want to route like this:

```
beego.Router("/detailed/[some-product-name]", &controllers.MainController{}, "get:Detailed")
```

i did try like below:

```
beego.Router("/detailed/:id", &controllers.MainController{}, "get:Detailed")
```

But all dependency files like js, bootstrap, css are expected in the path of `/detailed/static/` instead of `/static`.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you include your `js`, `bootstrap` files in html? You probably need to add absolut path to them, I mean by that to add `/` before path

Comment: i am using <script src="static/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
but its expecting /detailed/static/js/jquery.js if i tried to do beego.Router("/detailed/:id", &controllers.MainController{}, "get:Detailed").

Comment: so you should change it to <script src="`/`static/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and then everything should works. Apply this `/` to other too.

Comment: Excellent! it works! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's not a beego problem. You probably made your include scripts, stylesheets link relative. In your html (template), all file "improts" you should predate with `/` sign.
So if you have

`<script src="static/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

You need to change it to:

`<script src="/static/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`